# Why filelib:is_file() always returns false in ejabberd module?

Tags: erlang, ejabberd, erl

I wrote a module for `ejabberd`, in the module i checked existence of an image file. i used `filelib:is_file()` for that purpose.

when existence of image file checked in `ejabberd` module it always return `false`, but when i compile and run by `erl` program, it returns `true`.

Comment: Are the two Erlang VMs using different working directories, perhaps? You can check by calling `file:get_cwd()`.